# How to add SubView to a horizontal StackView programmatically to create Stripes?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a collectionView Cell with a StackView in it.

```
class OuterCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        for i in 1...30 {
            let tick = UIView()
            if i % 2 == 0 {
                tick.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            } else {
                    tick.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
            tick.tag = i
            tick.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            self.stackView?.insertArrangedSubview(tick, at:i)
        }
    }
```

I want to draw 30 cells on the stackView alternating between red and clear . Right now I am setting the index of the subview as well as the height with a auto layout anchor constraint and hoping that the .fillEqually distribution will compute the width and X locations of each of the subviews. However right now, it crashes when I try and set the height anchor and simply doesn't show anything when I remove the height anchor. How do I lay these out such that they are full height, and right next to each other with no margins?

Comment: Did you try setting heightAnchor of stack view?

Comment: @hardikparmar yes this crashes the app.

Comment: How were you adding the height Anchor constraint? Can you show us the code for that?

Comment: @hardikparmar its there in the code. 4 lines from the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you shouldn't be adding a height anchor here to items within your stackview. Automatically, things contained in the stack view are equal heights (or widths depending on stackview orientation). You shouldn't need to be setting sizes within the stackview directly. It defeats the purpose of the stackview in the first place.

Comment: when I don't add any constraints, it doesn't crash, but no red lines show up. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Also, try not to "insertArrangedSubview" since you are just adding them one after the other. Just use "addArrangedSubview(someSubview)". For the red color thing. Make sure that your modulo is triggering correctly. Throw a couple of print statements in there to see if it's actually being set. I'm going to try to run a version of this myself.

Comment: Hey, I was able to get it working just fine with your algorithm. Are you using an XIB file for the collectionview cell?

Comment: Im using a storyboard. The StackView is the same equal width and height of the cell using autolayout. hmm I wonder whats the difference

Comment: Just use a custom xib file and swift file. You want to copy your code and put it in the "awakeFromNib" method. Just register the nib in your VC like so.

`collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "OuterCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "OuterCollectionViewCell")`

Then just implement the collectionview delegates like normal.

Comment: then would let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "outerCell", for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell become let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OuterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell  inside of the cellForItemAt method?

Comment: `let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "OuterCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! OuterCollectionViewCell`

Comment: Just like that :)

Comment: Please mark the answer correct if it was, or post how you solved it as your answer.